# A Continuous function $f: \overline{B_1(0)} \subset \ell^2\to \mathbb{R}$ which does not reach the maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, special-functions

If necessary, recall that 
$$
\ell^2 = \{x=\{x_n\}_n\subset \mathbb{R} : \|x\|^2:=\sum_n |x|^2<\infty\}
$$

and $ \overline{B_1(0)} $ is the closed unit ball with respect to that norm.

> Can we find an explicit example of a continuous function $f: \overline{B_1(0)} \subset \ell^2\to \mathbb{R}$ which does not attain its maximum?

The point is that this ball is not a compact set.

Thank you.

Comment: As per my previous comment, your question still doesn't make the most sense. Can you maybe rephrase the **exact** question of the exercise in the body ?

Comment: No, sorry, I did a mistake in the question and now is correct. The point is to show a function satisfying the conditions mentioned in the question in order to convince by an example that it is not compact.

Comment: So it comes down to showing that $\overline{B_1^{\ell_2}}$ is not compact ?

Comment: I said no, and I say, again, no. I know by another proof that it is not compact. I repeat, the point is to give an example of this function.

Comment: Note that $f : \overline{B_1(0)} \in \ell_2$ isn't a solid expression for a function and this is why I am struggling to understand. Do you mean that you want to construct a function with its domain being the Unit Ball of $\ell_2$ such that it is a sufficient example in showing that it cannot be compact ? That's pretty straightforward using the defintiion of a compact operator.

Comment: Sorry, another mistake. It is because I am not on the computer and writing here is more complicated.

Comment: Maybe you can see it from this point of view, but the important thing here is not whether the ball is compact or not. I mean, knowing that this is not compact, I would like to illustrate it by a continuous function which does not reach the maximum. Sorry for the misunderstanding, and I hope now is everything okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-1/n) x_n^2$$ Note that $f(x) < 1$ for all $x \in \overline{B_1(0)}$, and you can get arbitrarily close to $1$...